# Setting an Apache environment variable in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache

How can I change the apache environment variable using node.js 
Basically am looking for something like apache_setenv() of PHP

Answer (score -1):

I think you want `export`

```
NODE_ENV=locahost
export NODE_ENV
```

or on 1 line  `export NODE_ENV=localhost`